# How is dojo.placed supposed to be written?

Tags: listbox, dojo

I am trying to place a select box with an id but I think I am not entering the parameters correctly on the dojo.place method because it is rendering in firefox but not IE:

```
var removeOpt = dojo.query('#sSec2 option');
    this._sec1 = new widget.StyledDropdown(dojo.byId("sSec1"), function(){
        dojo.hitch(sm, sm.collectInfo);

        //Make sure the second security question does not populate with the first security question option selected
        var el = this._el, selected = this.getValue();

        // empty out the other select menu
        //dojo.empty(dojo.byId('sSec2'));
        dojo.query("#sSec2 option").forEach(dojo.destroy);

        // looping thru the cached options for the second select menu
        dojo.forEach(removeOpt, function(that){
            if (that.value != selected) {
                dojo.place(that, dojo.byId('sSec2'));
            }
        });

        // rebuild
       Dropdowns.byId('sSec2').build();
    }, true);

    var removeOpt2 = dojo.query('#sSec1 option');
    this._sec2 = new widget.StyledDropdown(dojo.byId("sSec2"), function(){
        dojo.hitch(sm, sm.collectInfo2);

        //Make sure the first security question does not populate with the second security question option selected
        var el = this._el, selected = this.getValue();

        // empty out the other select menu
        //dojo.empty(dojo.byId('sSec1'));
        dojo.query("#sSec1 option").forEach(dojo.destroy);

        // looping thru the cached options for the second select menu
        dojo.forEach(removeOpt2, function(that){
            if (that.value != selected) {
                dojo.place(that, dojo.byId('sSec1'));
            }
        });

        // rebuild
        Dropdowns.byId('sSec1').build();
```

can I get some suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're calling it would add each as the (currently) last child of the node with id "sSec2".

http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojo/place

More importantly though, what is your if condition checking?  What is `selected`?  It's not quoted - is that intentional?

#### EDIT RE: updated code

Okay, the context brought in by the surrounding code raises a couple more potential troubleshooting points.

- is `this.getValue()` returning what you expect?  (presumably `true` or `false` to jive with the comparisons in question)

  - Maybe throw a console.log or alert inside those if statements to see if the code is even reaching there, ever?
- On your `dojo.hitch` lines, are you intending to execute that function?  If so, add another `()` at the end - `dojo.hitch` *returns* a function, doesn't execute it itself.
- Also, this may be irrelevant but I'm a tad bit curious - I'm assuming your `widget.StyledDropDown` doesn't extend `dijit._Widget`?  Since the arguments you're passing your constructor are in a completely different format.

Would it be possible for you to throw a (not-)working sample on http://jsfiddle.net/ ?